# Regular expression for hyperlinks used by SO/SE

Tags: support, implementation

What is the regular expression SO/SE sites use for making the hyperlink active?

There is a problem if the hyperlink is in the sentence, that it might be followed by interpunction. I see that if there is a dot or parenthesis at the end of hyperlink, it is not considered its part. So is it something like this?

```
preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/\S+[^),.?!])/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $s);
```

But I've seen a link which ended by `.` (dot), so this would break it.
It seems this will never work 100% (it can't), but I'm wondering what would be the optimal as-tweaked-as-possible solution.

Comment: [`(^|\s)(https?|ftp)(://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|\[\]\(\)!:,\.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|\[\]])($|\W)`](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/browse/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs#1451)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/(^|\s)(https?|ftp)(:\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|\[\]\(\)!:,\.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|\[\]])($|\W)/gi
```

http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Converter.js#1205